# How can I fix "RPM Build Error: Bad exit status"

Tags: bash, centos, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to create and build a go **rpm package** in a **CentOS8** container. Upon running the `rpmbuild -ba onboarding.spec` command, I'm getting this error:

```
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.nAad2g
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/tiagoribeiro/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd /home/tiagoribeiro/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf onboarding-1.0
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/tiagoribeiro/rpmbuild/SOURCES/onboarding-1.0.tar.gz
+ /usr/bin/tar -xof -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd onboarding-1.0
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.nAad2g: line 41: cd: onboarding-1.0: No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.nAad2g (%prep)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.nAad2g (%prep)
```

I'm been +- following [this](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/05/21/build-your-own-rpm-package-sample-go-program#creating_the_spec_file) documentation online and it's mostly replicated. Don't understand why I'm getting this error. Here's my spec file:

```
Name:           onboarding
Version:        1.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        golang api
License:        GPLv3
Source0:        %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
BuildRequires:  systemd-rpm-macros
Provides:       %{name} = %{version}

%description
small go app

%global debug_package %{nil}
%prep
%autosetup

%build
go build -v -o %{name}

%install
install -Dpm 0755 %{name} %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/%{name}
install -Dpm 644 %{name}.service %{buildroot}%{_unitdir}/%{name}.service

%post
%systemd_post %{name}.service

%preun
%systemd_preun %{name}.service

%files
%dir %{_sysconfdir}/%{name}
%{_bindir}/%{name}
%{_unitdir}/%{name}.service

%changelog
```

Here's my rpmbuild file tree:

```
/home/tiagoribeiro/rpmbuild/
├── BUILD
│   ├── main.go
│   └── onboarding.service
├── BUILDROOT
├── RPMS
├── SOURCES
│   ├── onboarding-1.0.tar.gz
├── SPECS
│   ├── onboarding.spec
└── SRPMS
```

What do I need to change in order to be able to build this package?

Comment: Perhaps you should create the destination dir?

Comment: How can I do that? 
Sorry, I'm quite new to rpm, linux and what not. I thought the line:  
%{_bindir}/%{name}

Did that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpacking the distribution file `onboarding-1.0.tar.gz` is not creating a directory with the default name (`%{name}-%{version}`, which in this case is `onboarding-1.0`).  It looks like the tarball doesn't contain a directory at all, which is poor form.  You have two main alternatives:

1. repack the source so that it contains the wanted directory:

   ```
   cd ~
   mkdir onboarding-1.0
   tar -C onboarding-1.0 -xf ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/onboarding-1.0.tar.gz
   tar czf rpmbuild/SOURCES/onboarding-1.0.tar.gz onboarding-1.0
   ```

   OR
2. instruct rpmbuild to create the wanted directory itself, by adding a `-c` option to the `%autosetup` macro invocation:

   ```
   %prep
   %autosetup -c
   ```

I would choose option (1) if you are building the tarball yourself in the first place, but option (2) if you're using a tarball provided by someone else.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for taking the time. I did what you recommended, and now the error is on the %build phase. It runs:  
"cd /home/tiagoribeiro/rpmbuild/BUILD", then  
"cd onboarding-1.0", then 
"go build -v -o onboarding". 

 And the following error:  
"package .: no Go files in /home/tiago/rpmbuild/BUILD/onboarding-1.0
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.18hcsF (%build)"  

I reckon I could manually cp the files over there, but this doesn't seem like a decent approach. Seems like I did something wrong along the way /:

Comment: @TiagoRibeiro, the two detailed alternatives presented in this answer are based on the assumption that files `rpmbuild/BUILD/main.go` and `rpmbuild/BUILD/onboarding.service` came from rpmbuild unpacking the original `onboarding-1.0.tar.gz` tarball.  If that's not the case then the diagnosis of the problem is the same, but there is not enough information to suggest a specific mitigation.

Comment: Note also that you must not perform alternative (1) more than once, and you must not do both (1) and (2).